# MVC 5 - Add a claim to a user

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, claims-based-identity, asp.net-identity-2, claims

I am developing a MVC 5 internet application and am using `Identity 2.1`.

How can I add a `claim` to a user, after the user has logged in, where I knows the `username`?

Here is what I have:

```
public void AddClaimToUser(string userName, string type, string value )
{
    var AuthenticationManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
    var Identity = new ClaimsIdentity(userName);
    Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(type, value));
    AuthenticationManager.AuthenticationResponseGrant = new AuthenticationResponseGrant(new ClaimsPrincipal(Identity), new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = true });
}
```

However, after I call this method, and I check the claims for the user, the added `claim` is not listed.

Here is the code that I am using to get the claims in a controller:

```
var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
IEnumerable<Claim> claims = identity.Claims;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

First Of all you have to create a method for add claim under IdentityModels.cs  class.like this,in below code i have created a claim for CompanyId.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  public bool IsActive { get; set; }
  public int? CompanyId { get; set; }


public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
{

  var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

  userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("CompanyId", (this.CompanyId + "" ?? "0")));

  return userIdentity;
}}
```

After write above code,you need to write one more method in IdentityConfig.cs

```
public static class IdentityExtensions{
public static int CompanyId(this IIdentity identity)
{
 return Convert.ToInt32(((ClaimsIdentity)identity).FindFirst("CompanyId").Value);
}}
```

After this you can get your created claim in any controller by just typing..

```
 int companyId = User.Identity.CompanyId();
```

Answer (score 0):

Giving `AuthenticationResponseGrant` is not enough to add claim to already logged in user. You need to get identity, add new claim ( you already do this), then sign user out and sign-in again. I pretty much do this in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24182444/809357)