# How to login into other person account - EF6 Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, identity, asp.net-identity-2

I have a ASP.NET MVC 5 WebApp using EF6. I've used identity for managing user account. Now I've a  structure that under a user there can be sub users. Now what if I need to log in into sub user account without knowing his password?
The password is stored encrypted in DB.

Is that possible?
If not what are the work around.

Comment: Why do you need to log into other user's accounts? I've never needed to do this.

Comment: Perhaps you can do some magic with Roles?

Comment: The point of having different accounts is to NOT be able to do that. Superuser should have role or claims to modify what his subusers can, but not to log with their accounts

Comment: It's very useful, for viewing pages as though you're the user. You can see what the user sees, and makes finding their specific issues much easier.

Comment: I think this is a very interesting problem regardless of whether its a good idea to implement . FYI you might want to hash all of the users details otherwise there could be an issue with legal stuff .California for instance has the [Online Privacy Protection Act](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_Privacy_Protection_Act) . So you would have to be very explicit in your privacy policy that the admin has this type of control.

Comment: Maybe this helps you:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24161782/how-do-i-use-asp-net-identity-2-0-to-allow-a-user-to-impersonate-another-user][1]