# ASP.NET Identity - making actions on behalf of someone

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have few BL functions that checking who is invoking a method by reading the data from httpContext.User property. It works great when the user really SignIn to the system.

I would like to allow users to schedule an action to be run on a later time. Once the user asks to send an email later, i am writing the request to the DB and the automation service i developed will execute it on the right time by making an http call like: https://mysystem.lan/SendEmail/?Requestid=122d8f273465.

since the automation process not happens in the client side, the user is not logged in to the system so the action SendEmail will not run because the httpContext.User property will be null.

Thanks to the parameter Requestid in the url, i can resolve the UserId who created the request and i want to mock the ASP.NET Identity to be the identity of that user and that the GetUserId() extension method will work too (since mocking not affects that kind of methods).

All the answers i saw here explaining how to mock the identity by creating an instance of the controller for unit testing but this situation is different because i need to mock the identity inside inside the controller action when the server is getting the request https://mysystem.lan/SendEmail/?Requestid=122d8f273465.

Can you suggest how to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use ASP.NET Identity 2.0 to allow a user to impersonate another user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24161782/how-do-i-use-asp-net-identity-2-0-to-allow-a-user-to-impersonate-another-user)

Comment: Jasen, Its not duplication. the link you mentioned will also create the autentication cookies and i am looking for a way to mock the httpcontext.

Comment: Why are you calling a controller method to send the email. That should be just a separate schedules background service - it makes no difference if the user is logged in at the time